# Outlook 2019: two calendars for one mail address

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

I have Outlook 2019, Version 1910 (Build 12130.20272) and am on Windows 10 1903 as a domain user.

I have the following (only) language options: English (US) is the only added language which I use as my display language and I have added the de_DE keyboard layout there. Most of my Windows is either in English or German (which is a bug and I gave up on trying to get everything in English as it is a total clusterfuck; however, this is not really my problem but I think it adds to my problem).

[image: language options]

My Outlook has all menus in German.

Now to my problem. I have only one mailbox (xxx@domain.tdl) but I have two calendars that seem to be connected with this. One “Kalender xxx@domain.tdl” and one “Calendar”

[image: my 2 calendars]

This is already strange that one is in German and the other is not.

- When I get event invitations to xxx@domain.tdl and accept them they will be added to “Kalender xxx@domain.tdl” but not the other one
- My colleagues can only see my “Kalender xxx@domain.tdl”
- And the other “Calendar” has all my old appointments that are
  recurring and all other ones from before last week
- The problem started occurring last week and I have no older
  appointments in my “Kalender xxx@domain.tdl” than last week
- I can delete “Calender” which I do not want as all my appointment series are in this calender
- I cannot delete “Kalender xxx@domain.tdl”
- I get reminders from appointments in both calenders
- I am using this mailbox from only one computer

How do I solve this clusterfuck without losing any appointments and can someone explain to me what happened?

I‘ve had this problem already a few months ago and it went away without me doing something actively (I updated Windows and also maybe Outlook, dunno; but I did not change or update anything on purpose to solve this problem).

Comment: Please make sure you set the mailbox of your default account as the default Data File via File-> Account Settings-> Account Settings...-> tab Data Files.     Besides, you can also press Win + R, type “outlook /resetfoldernames”, press Enter and restart your Outlook. If the issue persists, try creating and using a new Outlook profile via Control Panel > Mail > Show profile and see if there is any difference.

Comment: @Aidan Data Files is set like you described and I‘ve tried `outlook /resetfoldernames` a few times already and it did not help. I‘m gonna try your last suggestion in the next few days

Answer (score 0):

for me it worked microsoft solution:

Download MFCMAPI from
https://github.com/stephenegriffin/mfcmapi/releases/tag/21.0.21127.03
Download: MFCMAPI.x64.exe.21.0.21127.03.zip

Open the exe

Tools → Options → scroll down, set flagg by Use the MDB_ONLINE flag….., and Use the MAPI_NO_CACH flag…. Click on OK

Go to Session, Logon and choose the Profil, double click on the mailbox and open the Root Container,
All Settings are now in “Oberste Ebene des Informationsspeichers” (OEdI)
Open OEdI
Open from the calander which should no longer the primary calender the Attribute “PR_ENTRYID” and copy the Binary
Now Open the calender which should be the primary calender and Past the Attribute in “PR_ENTRYID”
Open now “Posteingang/Inbox” open Attribute “PR_IPM_APPOINTMENT_ENTRYID” and past the ID from your primary calender.

Refresh the view and can close MFCMAPI.

Now your Appointmants should be come in your primary calender.

When it successfull you can delete the calender with MFCMAPI.

It could be possible that the outlook client needs some time. Check OWA :)

Best regards
Robin

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I cannot test it though since I've switched laptops since then and did not have the problem on my new setup. So I cannot test and then accept the answer.

Comment: I have the exact same issue as OP (except my language is NO), but your answer has a few "quirks" about it. I have to admit, not having -any- punctuation or paragraphs makes the middle part of your answer very hard to read and test, but I think I found what you meant.
However, it did not work, as when I pasted the binary of the "wrong" calender into the "right" one, it won't let me save the entry, as it detects discrepancies in regards to what it expects the information to be.
Hence, getting to the “PR_IPM_APPOINTMENT_ENTRYID” step is not possible.